# Label control with picture on the right side no visible

Tags: vb.net

I try to build a custom label with image on left side .
But after to build and insert on my form and setup all the config, 
i only have the text present.
Why is the picturebox not apear on my form wen i insert on the form is only the label visible.
How can i solve this.
Tank you in advance
This is my code

```
Public Class label_picture

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    Label1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    Me.ForeColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
Public Property image As Image
    Get
        Return image
    End Get
    Set(image As Image)
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = image
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
        Me.Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property
Public Property text_labelpic_text As String
    Get
        Return text_labelpic_text
    End Get
    Set(text_labelpic_text As String)
        Label1.Text = text_labelpic_text
        Me.Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub Label1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.TextChanged
    Label1.Text = text_labelpic_text
    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub label_picture_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.SizeChanged
    Label1.Location = New Point(CInt(Me.Width / 2 - Label1.Width / 2), CInt(Me.Height / 2 - Label1.Height))
    Label1.Top = (Label1.Parent.Height \ 2) - (Label1.Height \ 2)
    PictureBox1.Location = New Point(CInt(Me.Width / 2 - PictureBox1.Width / 2), CInt(Me.Height / 2 - PictureBox1.Height))
    PictureBox1.Top = (PictureBox1.Parent.Height \ 2) - (PictureBox1.Height \ 2)
    PictureBox1.Left = (PictureBox1.Parent.Width \ 2) - (PictureBox1.Width \ 2)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hard to make the call when you don't show us how this UserControl is getting used in the client app.  But that SizeChanged event handler does not look very healthy, the label overlaps the picture box.  The normally sensible way is to have the picturebox at the top (Top = 0) and the label at the bottom (Bottom = Me.ClientSize.Height - Label1.Height).  And further improve it by setting the size of the picturebox so it always fits the available space.  Using BackgroundImage is odd as well, you'd certainly favor the Image property so the image gets rescaled to fit.

Comment: The question's title states that the PictureBox should be on the right, the question's text describes the opposite, your code implies that you're trying to center it. Btw, Top/Left and Location are the same coordinates. What is the `Parent`, here? Is it actually something other than `Me`? Btw2, this looks ike a UserControl, but you're saying that you want *to build a custom label*...